# SharePoint REST - Fetch list items w/ skiptoken gives HTTP 403

Tags: list, rest, powershell, sharepoint-online

I am GETting a bunch of list items from a SharePoint Online site using a PowerShell script. I need to fetch all the items, using the

`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items`

REST call.
I can call this endpoint just fine and receive the first 100 items. But when I call the URL for "skiptoken" which I received in the response, I get a `HTTP 403 (Forbidden)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling around I decided to resort back to using the CSOM and CAML query. This is not as flexible as the REST service and makes working on the result a little harder, but did the trick (code functional, but might be a good idea to split this up):

```
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($user , $password)
$context.Credentials = $credentials

$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$query.ViewXml = '...'

$web = $ctx.Web
$lists = $web.Lists
$list = $lists.GetById($listID)

$ctx.Load($lists)
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$resultCollection = New-Object 'System.Collections.ArrayList'

do {

    $items = $list.GetItems($query)
    $ctx.Load($items)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    $items | ForEach-Object {
        $item = #process item here
        $resultCollection.Add($item) |Out-Null
    }

    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $items.ListItemCollectionPosition #advance cursor

} while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```